# Power Query m Language Convert List to Single String Value with Separator

Tags: excel, syntax, powerbi, powerquery, m

```
{"Top 3 Max Sales Per Day", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.MaxN([Item Quantity Final], 3), each Number.ToText(_),",")), type number}
```

The Output Column is Still providing Error in each cell and I can't get the desired result to have the top 3 max values in one cell

Comment: That result type can't really be a number.

Comment: Hard to reproduce your error with what you've posted.  Please **edit** your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and **also** provide the text of the error message.